# Are there any services (a la Urban Airship) that implement a backend for the new auto-renewing subscriptions?

Tags: ios, subscriptions

Can't seem to find one that wouldn't also require my own server.

Extra credit if it doesn't require push notifications to work.

Comment: The point of this is for an API. Trying to simplify it to not require users of the api to need a server.

Comment: Urban Airship supports Auto-Renewing Subscriptions and as far as I know you don't need a server to use it.